# How to insert transformations hard coded i a query when there's no lookup table

Tags: t-sql

I have to insert records into our erp from our crm for ethnic origin. The codes are not in a table. How do I insert and do

```
if EthnicOrigin = Hispanic EthnicCategory = H, etc.

AI  =   American Indian or Alaska Native

INSERT INTO Person 
           (CODE, ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, EthnicCategory, CREATE_DATETIME)
     SELECT
           CODE, ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, EthnicOrigin, CREATE_DATETIME 
           FROM         Changes


CRM                 ERP 
EthnicOrigin        EthnicCategory  

H   =   Hispanic    
AI  =   American Indian 
A   =   Asian   
B   =   Black or African American   
P   =   Native Hawaiian 
W   =   White
```

sql server 2008r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression within your `select`:

```
insert into Person(CODE
                  ,ID
                  ,FIRST_NAME
                  ,MIDDLE_NAME
                  ,LAST_NAME
                  ,CREATE_DATETIME
                  ,EthnicCategory
                  )
select CODE
      ,ID
      ,FIRST_NAME
      ,MIDDLE_NAME
      ,LAST_NAME
      ,CREATE_DATETIME
      ,case EthnicOrigin
           when 'H'  then 'Hispanic'    
           when 'AI' then 'American Indian'
           when 'A'  then 'Asian'
           when 'B'  then 'Black or African American'
           when 'P'  then 'Native Hawaiian'
           when 'W'  then 'White'
         else 'No Ethnicity'
         end as EthnicCategory
from Changes;
```